# função zoom em javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas

Eu gostaria de criar uma função zoom dentro de um arquivo de extensão js, eu já tenho uma função canvas, no entanto no meu desenho está saindo muito pequeno dependendo das coordenadas iniciais, por isso gostaria de algo que quando precisasse eu pudesse dar um zoom na figura. Minha função canvas é:

```js
function fcanvas(){
var scale = 1;
var originx = 0;
var originy = 0;
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath(); 
ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000'; 
ctx.lineWidth = 2; 
ctx.font='20px Arial';
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(500,250) 
ctx.lineTo(500,250-(aa)); 
ctx.lineTo(500-(-bb),250 ); 
ctx.lineTo(500,250); 
ctx.font='12px Arial';
ctx.fillText("Tela 1000x500",20,20);
ctx.stroke(); 
}
```

Gostaria de algo fácil, ou algo que fosse bem detalhado, pois estou começando a aprender a programar e não sei muitas tag ainda.

Comment: Você quer que o `canvas` continue do mesmo tamanho, somente o que está desenhado nele aumente em escala, ou quer que o próprio `canvas` cresça junto com tudo o que tem dentro dele (sem você precisar mudar a forma de desenhá-lo)? Ambas as possibilidades existem, só não ficou claro pra mim o que você pretende.

Comment: Eu quero que somente o que está desenhado no canvas que aumente, deixando ele do mesmo tamanho

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você quiser que o `canvas` inteiro aumente de tamanho, inclusive seu conteúdo desenhado, você pode usar a propriedade CSS [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/transform) (que se aplica a qualquer elemento HTML). Se por outro lado o que você pretende é que *o conteúdo desenhado* aumente de tamanho, basta aplicar a transformação [`scale`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/scale) no contexto do `canvas` (usando o [`save`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/save) e o [`restore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/restore) para limitar que parte será escalonada).

Exemplo com ambas as transformações:

```js
var zoomXY = 1;   // Zoom (mesmo pro x e pro y)
var escalaXY = 1; // Escala (mesma pro x e pro y)

function fcanvas(){
var scale = 1;
var originx = 0;
var originy = 0;
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height); // Limpa o canvas antes de desenhar
ctx.save();                             // Salva as transformações
ctx.scale(escalaXY, escalaXY);          // Aplica a escala
  
ctx.beginPath(); 
ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000'; 
ctx.lineWidth = 2; 
ctx.font='20px Arial';
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(500,250) 
ctx.lineTo(500,250-(aa)); 
ctx.lineTo(500-(-bb),250 ); 
ctx.lineTo(500,250); 
ctx.font='12px Arial';
ctx.fillText("Tela 1000x500",20,20);
ctx.stroke(); 
  
ctx.restore();                          // Reseta as transformações
}

function zoom(dv) {
  zoomXY += dv;
  document.getElementById("myCanvas").style.transform = "scale(" + zoomXY + ")";
}

function escala(dv) {
  escalaXY += dv;
  fcanvas();
}

var aa = 100;
var bb = 100;
fcanvas();
```

```css
canvas {
    border: 4px solid black; /* Apenas para ajudar na visualização */

    transform: scale(1);   /* Transformação original (escala 100%) */
    transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

```html
Zoom no canvas:
<button onclick="zoom(0.1);">+</button>
<button onclick="zoom(-0.1);">-</button>
Zoom no conteúdo:
<button onclick="escala(0.1);">+</button>
<button onclick="escala(-0.1);">-</button>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="1000", height="500"></canvas>
```

Comment: Eu não estou conseguindo executar esse código, copiei igual está ai, e não consigo executa a minha função escala

Comment: @Isabela O que está acontecendo de errado? Da forma como está, é necessário que as funções `escala` e `zoom` estejam no *top-level*, se você estiver usando jQuery por exemplo e as funções estiverem dentro do `$(document).ready(function() { ... });` então é necessário atribuir o `click` do botão a partir do código JS. Ou o problema é outro, tipo as funções estão sendo chamadas mas algo de errado acontece? Apareceu alguma mensagem de erro no log?