# Eixos de um plano cartesiano mudando de acordo com o zoom HTML5(canvas) + JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas, gráfico

Galera é o seguinte, estou fazendo com `js` + `html5` e `canvas` um programa para plotar gráficos:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] 
Gostaria de implementar um zoom + e -, como na imagem, e voltar ao zoom original ao clicar em '='.
A minha dificuldade esta no seguinte: após dar o zoom, os eixos cartesianos 'x' e 'y' tem que mudar os seus valores não é ?

Exemplo: http://jsxgraph.uni-bayreuth.de/wp/examples/, após apertar o botão de '+' os valores dos eixos mudam, outro exemplo é o gráfico do google, após dar o zoom os valores do eixos mudam.

Eu queria mais ou menos isso, queria a idéia de como fazer isso, mudar os valores dos eixos de acordo com o zoom, ou exemplos já prontos, ou alguma solução parecida!!!

Comment: Estava vendo a documentação do `canvas` quando me deparei com a propriedade `ctx.scale(2, 2)`, acredito que pode trabalhar com ela

Comment: Aqui uma resposta pra sua pergunta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/61161/14262

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio, nao é isso que eu quero, acho que voce entendeu errado, esse efeito de zoom e scale eu ja tenho, esta funcionando perfeitamente, o que eu quero é, que apos aumentar o zoom ou scale (tanto faz) os valores dos eixos mudem, como no exemplo aqui: http://prntscr.com/7wh9dt apos dar o zoom os eixos ficaram mudaram o valor http://prntscr.com/7wh9jt, e assim vai mudando o valor a cada click, o que eu quero é isso.

Comment: Acho que não há necessidade de fazer isso, mas você pode usar o valor da escala pra aplicar a cada x e y dessa forma: `novoX = valorDaEscala + x`  ; `novoY = valorDaEscala + y`

Comment: Nao sei se aplicaria muito bem isso, porque a minha escala ja começa com 50, como ficaria? E a cada click a scale é acrestado + 25, ou seja, começa com 50, depois 75 depois 100 depois 125...(considerando o que estou clicando no '+'. Nao entendi muito bem o que voce quis dizer; Lemrando que, o que é modificado a cada click é a escala, nao o zoom, o zoom é sempre fixo,

Comment: Descarte meu ultimo comentario! Nao entendi como ficaria as modificações dos eixos de acordo com o click, pq a minha escala inicial é 1, ou seja, ctx.scale(1,1), é fixo esse valor, nunca muda. O que eu mudo a cada click, é a escala da 'linha' da função, somente a 'linha' da função é mudada a sua escala, nao a tela toda.  http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_scale.asp ): perceba que quando aumenta a escala, a borda da linha tmb muda, entao ficaria muito 'escroto' aumentar a scale da tela toda, entao eu tenho uma variavel scale, que determina a scale somente da linha da minha função

Answer (score 1):

Código adaptado de: http://jsfiddle.net/ndYdk/7/

Com o fator da escala você aplica somente ao desenho de dentro(aos pontos do interior do canvas) sem se preocupar com o tamanho do canvas.

```js
function desenhar(escala, posicao){
  var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  
  context.save();
  context.translate(posicao.x, posicao.y);
  context.scale(escala, escala);
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(80, 50);
  context.bezierCurveTo(20,-100, -139, -80, -30, 50);
  context.closePath();

  context.fillStyle = 'blue';
  context.fill();

  context.stroke();
  context.restore();
}

var iniciar = (function(){
  var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");

  var posicao = {
    x: canvas.width / 2,
    y: canvas.height / 2
  };

  var escala = 1.0;
  var fatorMultiplicacao = 0.8;

  document.getElementById("plus").addEventListener("click", function(){
    escala /= fatorMultiplicacao;
    desenhar(escala, posicao);
  }, false);

  document.getElementById("minus").addEventListener("click", function(){
    escala *= fatorMultiplicacao;
    desenhar(escala, posicao);
  }, false);

  desenhar(escala, posicao);
}());
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" style="width: 300px;"></canvas>
<input type="button" id="plus" value="+">
<input type="button" id="minus" value="-">
```

Comment: Entendi marcelo, mas a minha dúvida nao é essa, o meu grafico ele ta zoom, com esse mesmo exemplo que vc postou, a minha dúvida é essa, a cada click no '+', aqueles numeros mudarem de valor, como no exemplo acima, a cada click no '+' (no grafico do google) os numeros dos eixos mudam, eu quero isso, que eles mudem, o meu grafico da o zoom, ele cresce tranquilo, so que os numeros dos eixos cartesianos nao acompanham o crescimento, eles ficam 'parado', exe: http://prntscr.com/7wmchd, depois de 3 clicks no '+' > http://prntscr.com/7wmcza. Percebeu que os numeros dos eixos 'y' nao mudaram ?

Comment: Eu queria que o valor '1' que esta na primeira imagem, acompanhasse o crescimento, ou seja, a cada click o '1' fosse subindo junto com o grafico

Comment: Sim entendi, poste o código da sua função

Comment: http://pastebin.com/izNpcGPV, o codigo esta meio 'tosco' até pq estou apgando ele muito, mas irei deixar 'certo'. A função showAxes(context), é que plota os eixos 'x' e 'y' tem 2 laços de repetição, um para cada eixo, para plotar tambem os numeros. qualquer coisa me adiciona skype. fillipe.santos6

Comment: Tem como criar um http://jsfiddle.net/ ja com o HTML minimo embutido? ficaria bem mais fácil editar

Comment: Estou tendo dificuldade para colocar lá, sao uns 4 arquivos js's e css